# Range error при cast HMENU to integer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

При открытии формы в программе ей в свойство Tag записывается handle TMenuItema с которого она была открыта. Для TMenuItem устанавливается Enabled=false. При закрытии формы для TMenuItem этой формы делается Enabled=true.

Проблема такая: иногда возникает Range check error на строчке:

```
form.Tag := item.Handle;
```

Сам item.Handle имеет тип HMENU, а Tag - integer. Я так понимаю, что проблема в том что в item.Handle хранится слишком большое число для Integer.

Можно ли безопасно сделать cast из HMENU в integer? В с++ для этих целей вроде есть функции IntToPtr и PtrToInt, но в delphi я их не нахожу. Или возможно можно решить по-другому мою проблему, без создания в каждой форме выделенного свойства типа HMENU?

Предполагается что проект должен работать на любой платформе. Сам проект компилируется иногда из под 32 битной системы, иногда с 64

```
procedure TFrmMain.CreateForm;
begin   
   //создание  FrmChild ...
   ProcessMenuItem(tMenuItem(Sender), FrmChild);  
end;

procedure TFrmMain.ProcessMenuItem(item: TMenuItem; form: TForm);
begin    
  item.Enabled := false;
  form.Tag := item.Handle;    
end;

procedure TfrmChild.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  //при закрытии формы активируем MenuItem
  frmMain.BeforeCloseChild(tForm(Sender)); 
  Action := caFree;
  Child:=nil;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.BeforeCloseChild(ChildForm: tForm);
begin
  frmMain.MainMenu1.FindItem(ChildForm.tag, fkHandle).Enabled := true;
end;
```

Comment: У вас бинарники собираются под 32 или 64 бит платформу? (хотя вроде ХЕ1 не умела х64, точно под ней собираете?)

Comment: предполагается что проект должен работать на любой платформе. Сам проект компилируется иногда из под 32 битной системы, иногда с 64

Comment: Это важное дополнение. Включите это в текст вопроса.

Comment: Использование свойств `Tag` у компонентов - это первый признак плохой архитектуры приложения и повод задуматься о ее (архитектуры) изменении. Придумайте другой способ реализации требуемого функционала. Добавьте в `FrmChild` публичное поле типа `HWND` или сразу `TMenuItem`, как вам советует @KromStern.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Плюсую. Но замечу, что `Tag` для того и полезен, что в него можно по-быстрому что-то вмонстрячить. Только надо обращать внимание, что не все в него влезет.

Comment: @KromStern вообще-то все, смотри мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше сделать так:

```
TFrmChild = class(TForm)
...
public
  UsedMenuItem: TMenuItem;
end;

...

procedure TFrmMain.ProcessMenuItem(item: TMenuItem; form: TForm);
begin    
  item.Enabled := false;
  if (Assigned(form) and (form is TFrmChild)) then
    (form as TFrmChild).UsedMenuItem := item;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.BeforeCloseChild(ChildForm: tForm);
begin
  if (Assigned(ChildForm)
    and (ChildForm is TFrmChild) 
    and (Assigned((ChildForm as TFrmChild).UsedMenuItem)))
  then
    (ChildForm as TFrmChild).UsedMenuItem.Enabled := True;
end;
```

---

Но если вам очень хочется, можете оставить старый вариант с небольшими изменениями:

```
procedure TFrmMain.ProcessMenuItem(item: TMenuItem; form: TForm);
begin    
  item.Enabled := false;
  form.Tag := NativeInt(item.Handle);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.BeforeCloseChild(ChildForm: tForm);
begin
  frmMain.MainMenu1.FindItem(HMENU(ChildForm.tag), fkHandle).Enabled := true;
end;
```

Поскольку поле Tag имеет тип `NativeInt`, а не просто `Integer`, то при компиляции под х64 это поле будет занимать 8 байт. `item.Handle` типа `HMENU`, который под x64 тоже 8 байт.

Проблема была в том, что `NativeInt` - это **знаковое** целое  (4 или 8 байт), а `HMENU` - это **беззнаковое** целое (4 или 8 байт). И в случаях, когда значение типа `HMENU` было больше половины максимального, то в знаковое целое такой же длинны (в байтах) оно уже не помещалось. Явное преобразование `NativeInt(item.Handle)` говорит компилятору интерпретировать значение `item.Handle` как знаковое целое. А преобразование `HMENU(ChildForm.tag)` наоборот, говорит компилятору интерпретировать значение `ChildForm.tag` как беззнаковое целое.

По-этому преобразование `HMENU -> NativeInt` и обратно будет проходить без ошибок.

Обращайте внимание на предупреждения компилятора. Он должен был вас предупредить о том, что вы делаете что-то не так в том месте, где вы делали `form.Tag := item.Handle;`.

Comment: Да, вы правы, тип незаметно поменяли на `NativeInt`

Comment: @KromStern когда добавили компилятор под х64, тогда и поменяли =)

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на знак - HMENU беззнаковое, а integer со знаком. То есть вы при простом присвоении будете получать ошибку (если значение больше 2^31).

Для корректного присвоения, нужно сделать каст `Tag := NativeInt(Handle);` и соответственно обратный каст при чтении `HMenu(Tag)` (что идентично `NativeUInt(Tag)`)

---

"cast из HMENU в integer" сделать на х64 очевидно нельзя, т.к. на х64 системе первый хранит 64 бита информации, а второй только 32. Нельзя гарантированно и без потерь впихнуть большее в меньшее.

К счастью, как верно заметил kot-da-vinci, тип `Tag` в новых версиях поменялся на `NativeInt`, длина которого совпадает с длиной указателя. Дело только в знаковости (см. 1 абзац)

---

Самое правильное - добавляйте поле в форму. Ничего сложного в этом нет.